# How can I read a .dbf file with wso2 Data Services Server?

Tags: jdbc, wso2, dbf, wso2-data-services-server

the documentation of WSO2 Data services server say you can read any database with a JDBC driver, and I found that there are some JDBC libraries for .DBF files.

DSS documentation: http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/
JDBC for DBF files: http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_dbf_jdbc.htm

Someone has already done or did something similar?

I would appreciate your help

Comment: The answer is yes you can access dbf files with the right JDBC driver. Please ask a more specific question with a real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WSO2 DSS supports any RDBMS datasource type, provided a compatible driver is copied to the product. You can follow the below steps.

1. You can add the JDBC driver to the $DSS_HOME/repository/component/lib folder and start the server.
2. Create a dataservice by following the [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/Step+1%3A+Defining+the+Data+Service)
3. Add an RDBMS type [datasource](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/RDBMS), as DBF is not listed in the pre-defined datasource types, select 'Generic' and give the driver class name, connection url, username and password according to the DBF specified
4. Add query and then an operation. Our official documentation has all the necessary steps.

Please note that, we have not tested with this driver, therefore, to use in a production environment, a comprehensive testing cycle will be needed (including load tests, long running tests .. etc).

Comment: I used this driver [link](http://www.hxtt.com/dbf.html)  following yours steps and work prefect, Thank you!